# Can users of a suitable reputation be allowed to add short comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, comments

At a suitable reputation level, please could users be allowed to post short comments?

By suitable level I'm thinking of 7,500 reputation, and by short I mean 8 to 10.

At 7,500 rep, there hasn't been a privilege for a while, and there won't be for a while. On top of that, at that level users will know what is appropriate in a comment and what isn't.

Sometimes (not often) I find myself needing to post a short comment, and I end up adding `......` to it. Not only does it look unprofessional, it can confuse new users as to what the dots are there for.

I suggest 8 to 10 letters, because "Thank you" is 9 characters. I know that comments aren't meant to stick around, but sometimes it doesn't hurt to thank someone who edited in what you suggested - or tell someone that you've edited their suggestion in.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ^^simple (I didn't -1 btw)

Comment: it's a zero-space character. Can you copy this: `​​​​​` (there are quite a few in that code block) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm. I'd like this feature, but I understand why SE wouldn't specifically make this. Sorry!

Comment: ​​​​​  ​​​​​  ​​​​​

Comment: "*Sometimes (not often) I find myself needing to post a short comment, and I end up adding `......` to it*" Examples would have been good. If you have exact reasons then voice them :) Otherwise ShadowWizard's answer stands really.

Comment: All of your "thank you" examples can be readily accomplished by clicking the various question, answer, and comment voting buttons, as well as the "accept" button in some cases.

Comment: @JasonC doesn't mean people understand what that means, or that I want to upvote when they've done an edit.

Comment: Is your time so valuable that you can not write a few words more. Like "I thank you for that' instead of 'thanks'?

Comment: @Willeke that sounds clumsy to me.

Comment: @Tim, it can be any set of words, as long as they are over that very short limit. I am ESL, so my command of English is not 'natural'.

Comment: @Willeke I see your point... I'd like to be able to use just thankyou etc tho.

Comment: @Tim Hey, I have no objections to you adding "Thank yous" everywhere, I'm all about beefing up my NC / too-chatty flag count.

Answer (score 13):

Comment shorter than 15 characters is not worth posting in the first place.

Some example for such invalid comments:

1. Thanks!
2. Please do.
3. Really?

And probably many more, all can't be considered valid comments to begin with.

So - can't see any point in having such a feature added.

Comment: Hmm ​​​​​  ​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think we need this. Firstly, I don't think comments that short should be posted, but if you really need to send a short message and don't want to seem unprofessional or confuse anyone, you can do something like "Thank you @user" or add a ":)" (smiley face) at the end.*

<sup>*Some people may find smiley faces unprofessional, but this is not your work, this is SE. Smiley faces are perfectly acceptable.</sup>